# How to compare two directories and delete duplicate files

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu

How might I search two directories for files with the same name, size,type...and remove them from one of those directories?

Comment: @αғsнιη: this isn't exactly the same question, but a lot of working hints are in this previous question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have taken example of 2 directories p1  and p2

First i will save the output of p1  and p2 directories filenames to 2 output files

```
find /root/p1 -type f |awk -F "/" '{print $NF}'   > /var/tmp/P1_file.txt

 find /root/p2 -type f |awk -F "/" '{print $NF}'   > /var/tmp/P2_file.txt
```

Now i will find the common filenames in both directories  and delete in one of directories. I wish you delete the duplicate files in /root/p1 and keep the files in /root/p2

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1];next}($1 in a) {print $1}' /var/tmp/P1_file.txt /var/tmp/P2_file.txt  |awk '{print "rm -rvf" " " "/root/p1/"$1}' | sh
```

Tested and worked fine

Comment: Thank you, that worked!

Comment: How would you do this if you had to escape characters in the file path?

Comment: I tried this, but it appears to list the files in the first part (the find) without the directory path. This will be a problem if a file exists in more than one subdirectory.

Answer (score 13):

Using `fdupes`:

```
fdupes --delete dir1 dir2
```

`fdupes` will not test on filename or file type, but will test on file size and contents (which implicitly includes file type).

Example:

```
$ mkdir dir1 dir2

$ touch dir{1,2}/{a,b,c}

$ tree
.
|-- dir1
|   |-- a
|   |-- b
|   `-- c
`-- dir2
    |-- a
    |-- b
    `-- c

2 directories, 6 files

$ fdupes --delete dir1 dir2
[1] dir1/a
[2] dir1/b
[3] dir1/c
[4] dir2/a
[5] dir2/b
[6] dir2/c

Set 1 of 1, preserve files [1 - 6, all]: 1

   [+] dir1/a
   [-] dir1/b
   [-] dir1/c
   [-] dir2/a
   [-] dir2/b
   [-] dir2/c

$ tree
.
|-- dir1
|   `-- a
`-- dir2

2 directories, 1 file
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to use `dircmp` which exists on many Unixes.

See:

```
man dircmp
```

The `-d` option seems to be the one you might find the most appropriate:

```
dircmp -d dir1 dir2
```

will compare contents of `dir1` and `dir2` and display a `diff` like output.

Answer (score 3):

You have many options for your task. Instead of repeating the recommendations of those who answered before me, I'll add one with a different look and feel that you might be more comfortable with.

If you feel comfortable using `midnight commander`, which is an ncurses-based twin-panel file manager for the console, that program includes a graphical directory comparison feature.

The procedure for using it is to start with each directory visible in a panel, and then press either `C-x d` (the default keybinding), or `F9 c c` (the default hotkeys for the menu item).

Here's a redacted excerpt from the `mc` man page that describes the command and its three modes of operation:

```
  The "Compare directories" command compares the directory panels with
  each other. You can then use the Copy (F5) command to make the panels
  identical. There are three compare methods. The quick method compares
  only file size and file date. The thorough method makes a full
  byte-by-byte compare. The size-only compare method just compares the
  file sizes and does not check the contents or the date times, it just
  checks the file size.
```

When the comparison finishes, `mc` will select and visually higlight the files unique to the current directory. Thus, pressing `F5` will copy them to the other panel. In order to delete the files common to both directories, press `*` to toggle the selection (and note how `mc` now highlights the inverse of what was highlighted before), and press `F8` to delete.

Comment: `midnight commander` is such a great tool for managing a headless file server. thanks for making it even more usefull with that answer!

Answer (score 2):

[rmlint](http://rmlint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) has options to do this:

```
rmlint -T duplicates --match-basename --keep-all-tagged --must-match-tagged /duplicates // /originals
```

(the '//' separator identifies "tagged" paths for the *--keep-all-tagged* and *--must-match-tagged* switches)

After finding duplicates, *rmlint* creates an executable script *rmlint.sh* that you can run (after checking) to delete the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you tagged your question as `ubuntu` which normally comes with a graphical desktop, so here are a few graphical desktop options:

1) If you are using the `nautillus` file manager, there exists a ubuntu package called `nautilus-compare` which integrates a directory comparison into the file manager you already use.

2) There also exists a stand-alone program called `meld` which performs both file and directory comparisons.

Comment: I am a frequent meld user and forgot it can do directories as well.

Answer (score 0):

Running any command with the `--delete` option makes me nervous, so I wrote the following script to search for files that are SHARED by both $DIR1 and $DIR2, but will only move the files from $DIR1 to a trash folder for later review leaving unique files behind. It also preserves the directory structure in the trash folder, making undeletion easy.

```
IFS=$'\n'
for file in `jdupes -r -T -T "$DIR1" "$DIR2" | awk -v p1="$DIR1" -v p2="$DIR2" '$0 ~ p1 && $0 ~ p2'  RS="\n\n" ORS="\n\n" | grep "$DIR1"`; do
    echo "$file" | grep -q "^$DIR1/duplicated_files/" && continue
    output="$DIR1/duplicated_files/`dirname "$file" | awk -v p="$DIR1/" '{sub(p, "")}1'`"
    mkdir -p "$output"
    echo "Moving $file"
    mv "$file" -t "$output"
done
```

This will leave behind empty directories which can be deleted with:

```
find "$DIR1" -type d -empty -printf "Deleting empty folder: " -print -delete
```